# How to trace source of $watch model updates in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my multi-user AngularJS app, I have a model object on my scope. This model can be manipulated by both user input and server updates.

I have a $watch observer to track the model and update the UI. Is it possible to determine the source/reason of my model update from within my $watch function? Without that check, I have problems with feedback loops (e.g. UI→Server→UI).

**UPDATE:** some code

Controller:

```
$scope.elementProperties = { left: 0 };

$scope.$watch('elementProperties.left', function(newVal, oldVal) { changeSelectedElementProperty('left', newVal, oldVal); } );
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.ui-editor').directive('myappPropertiesPanel', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/ui-editor/myappPropertiesPanel.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { elementProperties: '=' },

        link: function postLink (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('elementProperties.left', function(newVal, oldVal) { console.log('PropertiesPanel change left', newVal, oldVal); } );
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can't you just set some flag when data comes from a server / ui?

Comment: can you provide example? Flag makes sense, or perhaps using broadcast events might help

Comment: Or set up a new property on elementProperties, containing the last source of change

Comment: But how can I detect if the change happened from the UI (e.g. the `myappPropertiesPanel` directive)? `scope.$watch` seems to trigger in the order they were issued, so the controller `$watch` statement triggers before the directive does.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this is by using events instead of `$watch`

See [working plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mR35FA6kDbR32jVwk9La?p=preview)

In my plunker, I've put in a `$interval` that will simulate a web service call by changing the value every few seconds.

Here is what you can do.

In the `then` handler of your http call, before you set the new value retrieved from the web service to the model, publish an event with a payload containing the old value and the new value like below:

```
$http.get('url goes here')
 .then(function (response) {
     scope.$broadcast('UPDATE_FROM_SERVER',
                      {oldValue: scope.elementProperties.left, newValue: response.data.left});
     scope.elementProperties.left = response.data.left;
  };
```

Then, in your form control, where the user will change the value, attach an `ng-click` like below:

```
ng-change="userChangeHandler(elementProperties.left, '{{elementProperties.left}}')
```

Notice the quotes around `'{{elementProperties.left}}'`. This will ensure that the change handler function will get the old value of the property.

Now, you can listen to these change events like below:

```
  $scope.$on('UPDATE_FROM_SERVER', function (event, changes) {
    // This code will be invoked when the data is changed by the server
    $scope.messages.push('Data changed by Server from ' + changes.oldValue + ' to ' + changes.newValue);
  });

  $scope.$on('UPDATE_FROM_USER', function (event, changes) {
    // This code will be invoked when the data is changed by the user
    $scope.messages.push('Data changed by User from ' + changes.oldValue + ' to ' + changes.newValue);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to determine the source/reason of my model update from within my $watch function?"

The short answer is no, it is not possible to know the source of the change as the change is not marked at the time of change but rather on the following digest when the watcher tests oldWatchedValue === newWatchedValue and discovers that it fails the equality check. So there is nothing to bind the fact that there was a change to the source of the change.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to decouple the logic that happens on user input and server update.

One way you can do this is have the $watch always update the UI model. On IU side, use ng-model and ng-change. E.g.

```
<input ng-model="myModel" ng-change="watchMyModel(myModel)">
```

That way, when you hit your $scope.watchMyModel function, you will know that the changes came from the back-end.